# How to use MySQL command to display last minute (i.e current minute) row from the database?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM master_name;

+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
| name_id | name_dateadded      | name_datemodified   | firstname | lastname |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
|       1 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | John      | Smith    |
|       2 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | Jane      | Smith    |
|       3 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | Jimbo     | Jones    |
|       4 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | 2001-10-29 13:11:00 | Andy      | Smith    |
|       7 | 2001-10-29 14:16:21 | 2001-10-29 14:16:21 | Chris     | Jones    |
```

---

### Expected Output:

```
| 7 | 2001-10-29 14:16:21 | 2001-10-29 14:16:21 | Chris  | Jones |
```

Comment: i think you need the last id right?

Comment: Yes i need last id.@bjesua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM master_name
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(name_id) FROM master_name)
```

Comment: The above query works.If i need to use the same method for insert the max datas into new tables under new database name what should i use.@Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
SELECT MAX(name_id) FROM master_name
```

Comment: It works.Can i possible to use insert the max id into new database@bjesua

Comment: yes you can, you have to do something like this:  INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany'; @gpssago

Comment: But this query outputs only time field if i need entire eow what should i use@bjesua

Comment: @gpssago : This answer will return only the max name_id, not the row

Comment: you can insert any data you want, so if you select all you can insert the same values, just check your id, i think it's auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use a `LIMIT`.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM `master_name`
ORDER BY `name_id` DESC LIMIT 1;
```